# Does Apple care if I develop a software compatibility layer to run iOS apps on it?

Tags: macos

I was considering building a compatibility layer for Snow Leopard to run iOS apps on it without touch-screen controls so thay way you can have OS X and iOS running together.

Is there any terms against this?

Comment: Could you elaborate on why terms might exist to be "against" building software?

Answer (score 1):

### No.

Well, kind of.

If you *do* build such a thing, Apple probably won't allow it in the Mac App Store - that's my gut feeling. However, they wouldn't be able to keep you from distributing it on your own.

#### But...

<sub>Note: From this point on, I will only be talking about this idea. Nothing more. And don't get discouraged.</sub>

There's a problem here: architecture. From what I understand, you want to make an app-like-thing that allows you to run iOS apps on OSX.

Here's the thing: All modern OS X machines run on an Intel architecture. All modern iOS devices run on an armv7(s) architecture.

Why's that a problem? When an iOS developer compiles their code, the compiler that's all the little statements and methods and things and turns it into instructions.

Intel chips and armv7(s) chips have different architectures - meaning different instruction sets, meaning - well, you would have to get hold of the developer's *source code* for an app to be able to pull this off.

Not just one app - *every* app you want to run in this layer.

Still, there *might* be a way to do it. If you find it, you can make *lots* of money. Go be a crazy one!

Comment: Hardware emulation is key here.

Answer (score 0):

Since Apple has switched to ARM architecture in early 2021, Macs with the new Apple Silicon chip is going to be able to run iOS applications natively.  There's no longer a need to develop a compatibility layer like that.